# Is 'auto const' and 'const auto' the same?

Tags: c++, c++11, language-lawyer, constants, auto

Is there a semantic difference between `auto const` and `const auto`, or do they mean the same thing?

Comment: It's the same, like any other type.

Comment: I can provide a more accurate but legalistic answer. Since you didn't tag with language-lawyer, I'm going to assume, for now, that you don't want that much detail.

Comment: @ArneVogel you have your chance now :)

Answer (score 139, accepted):

The `const` qualifier applies to the type to the immediate left unless there is nothing to the left then it applies to the type to the immediate right. So yup it's the same.

Comment: If there is nothing left, then it is right (and vice versa) :-)

Comment: That's not really how it works, specifiers and qualifiers (that precede the *declarator*) may appear in any order, e.g. `long volatile unsigned const typedef long cvull;`. The type is neither (fully) to the left nor to the right of `const`.

Comment: @ArneVogel OMG, why `typedef` is allowed in the middle :)

Comment: As @ArneVogel commented, the answer is not completely correct. The fact that this is the accepted answer is misleading (and possibly dangerous).

Comment: @ArneVogel where could I read more about this please

Comment: The conclusion (that they are the same) is correct, but the logic is not quite right, because the `auto` can be composed of multiple stuff, eg `int *`. Thinking of `auto` as one big chunk with parentheses would be helpful, such as `(int *)`, not just `int *`.

Answer (score 30):

Contrived example:

```
std::vector<char*> test;
const auto a = test[0];
*a = 'c';
a = 0; // does not compile
auto const b = test[1];
*b = 'c';
b = 0; // does not compile
```

Both `a` and `b` have type `char* const`. Don't think you can simply "insert" the type instead of the keyword `auto` (here: `const char* a`)! The `const` keyword will apply to the whole type that `auto` matches (here: `char*`).

Comment: The const doesn't really apply to `char*`, it applies to the `char` part, not the `*` part.

Comment: @jbruni: But the example here seems to show the opposite: the `char` at the end is _not_ `const`, that's why you _can_ replace it. The _pointer itself_ is `const` (e.g. the "`*` part"), that's why you _cannot_ replace it.

Comment: @Sz. is right. jbruni's comment is the opposite. And one tiny [tip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10709897/is-auto-const-and-const-auto-the-same/10709973#comment136637134_10709973).